# Rails Nested routes undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep getting an

`undefined method 'orders_path' for #<#<Class:0x007faefee50a88>:0x007faefee414e8>`

when navigating to my new order path url `/users/1/orders/new`

Been stuck on this, not sure what the deal is.

Routes:

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'accounts'

  resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do
      resources :orders
  end
```

root index:

`<%= link_to "Create an Order", new_user_order_path(current_user.id) %>`

form:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @order]) do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

new:

```
<h1>New Order</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', user_orders_path(@user) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this:

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
```

Rails is looking for `orders_path`, but you don't really have such a route as you have defined your `orders` resource nested under the `users` resource. So, you have to pass both: `@user` and `@order` to the form like this:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @order]) do |f| %>
    # your code goes here
<% end %>
```

If you write the form this way, then Rails will look for this path: `user_orders_path` which will match your defined route and will work and you won't get this error anymore:

```
undefined method 'orders_path' for #<#<Class:0x007faefee50a88>:0x007faefee414e8>
```

So, this will fix your current issue. But, there is another issue in your `new.html.erb` file where you currently have this:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', user_orders_path %>
```

You have to pass the `@user` as an argument to this method:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', user_orders_path(@user) %>
```

otherwise, it will fail again.

Hope this helps to solve your problems.

Comment: Really? After you made the changes that mentioned in my answer you are getting the SAME error? At least it should be a DIFFERENT error if did not fix your problem.

Comment: could you please show your controller and view files?

Answer (score 0):

Since `orders` is nested on top of users, the `form_for` declaration will need to include both the user, and the order objects.

```
<%= form_for([@user, @order]) do |f| %>
```

Your `new` template will also need to have a reference to the given user.

```
<%= link_to 'Back', user_orders_path(@user) %>
```